# Adding notifications to my web app

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a chrome extension that allows users to chat with one another. I've finished the basic implementation and want to add notifications that tell a user if they've received a new chat message since the last time they were connected. I have an idea of how I want to implement it but need input on whether it seems feasible and suitable.

Basically, my database is structured so that there is a list of users and chatrooms. Each user has a section called `chats` which lists all the names of the chatrooms they're in:

[image: db]

What I plan to do is the following: In every chat under each user's `chats` section, instead of setting its value to `true`, I set it to the last time they disconnected. Then in each chatroom, I add another field after `user2` called `timeLastMessageSent` and always update it to the current time a new message is sent.

With that information, every time a user connects I'll loop through the chatroom's listed in their `chats` section and see if the value of `timeLastMessageSent` is higher than their last disconnect time, which means a message was sent while they were away and I can add some sort of notification that they have a new message.

I'm relatively new to firebase so if anyone with more experience can tell me what they think of my idea I'd really appreciate it. Is this idea feasible? Am I approaching the problem correctly? What sort of commands should I get familiar with to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Tracking by timestamp is a cheap way to know what message a user last had a chance to see. If you run into any problems while implementing, post back with the minimal code to reproduce that problem and we'll try to help.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for the response. Just to be sure, I'd want to use the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` thing from these docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.ServerValue, right?

Comment: That would be one way. If your keys are chronological (for example if you use Firebase push ids), you could also just track the most recent push id the user has seen.

Comment: I am using push! I didn't know they were chronological, I thought they were random.

Comment: see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html